# MariaDB UPDATE replacing double quotes with empty string throws error 1064

Tags: mariadb, sql-update

I am trying to remove double quotes from saved strings: using DBeaver, but also tried command line:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value REPLACE(meta_value, '"', '')
where meta_key = 'cstnfo_spot_1_kvm_ID'
;
```

And the SQL-Error is:

```
SQL-Fehler [1064] [42000]: (conn=279) You have an error [...] near 'REPLACE(`meta_value`, '"', '')
```

I've tried REPLACE(meta_value, '"', '') and (meta_value, '\"', '') since I want to find the double quote " and remove it from the string.

Comment: You've tried REPLACE(meta_value, '\'\'', '')?

Comment: I've tried REPLACE(meta_value, '\"', '') and (meta_value, '\\"', '') since I want to find the double quote " and remove it from the string.

Comment: Gotcha, you above code is missing an '=', should be:
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '\"', '')
WHERE meta_key = 'cstnfo_spot_1_kvm_ID'
;

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As bschellekens pointed out in the comments, I just missed the '=', so it should be:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '"', '')
where meta_key = 'cstnfo_spot_1_kvm_ID'
;
```